# How to force maven to download optional dependencies for off line env

Tags: maven, spring-boot

As stated in the title.
I want to use spring boot in a project that is run in off line environment.

I have problems deploying my project because some of spring dependencies are optional and were not downloaded.

I do not want to specify and manually download each optional dependency.

What can be done?

Comment: Have you added the dependencies in maven ? Both optional and required ones ?

Comment: Can you describe why you need the optional dependencies for your offline development?

Comment: Since it's not clear but as I understand you need different dependency for the different environments.  If its the case you can use different maven profile and add dependencies under the desired profile. After that run with ``` mvn -PprofileName```

Comment: On the pc with the external network I use dependency:resolve/dependency:sources and on the pc with the internal network the docker image I use uses install. Maybe thats why?